# List the attached PDF, and category from posts. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, list, pdf, attachment

I'm trying to make a custom Wordpress template/page where I list the attached PDFs from posts in several sub-categories.
I have found several snippets, but I can't get them to work.
My PHP skills are somewhat limited.

This gets me all the attached PDFs, but I want 4 different lists, one for each category.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
    'post_parent' => null,
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); 
    ?>
        <ul class="">
            <li class=""><h2>Sub-Category-Name</h2>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <?php
                the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
                echo '</li>';
                }
                } 
                ?>
```

Comment: Have a read [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pulling-attachments-from-specific-post-categories).

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to solve it to a certain degree. Right now I run this four times on the page, with different category names in each loop.

```
                <ul>
                <?php query_posts('category_name=your-category-name &posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php
                            $args = array(
                                'order'          => 'ASC',
                                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                                'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
                                'post_status'    => null,
                                'numberposts'    => 1,
                                );
                                $attachments = get_posts($args);
                                if ($attachments) {
                                    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                                        echo "<li><a href='";
                                        echo the_permalink();
                                        echo "' title='";
                                        echo the_title();
                                        echo "'>";
                                        echo the_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
                                        echo "</a></li>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </ul>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```